# Zoom in/Zoom out using React-PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf.js, react-pdf

In my ReactJS application I need to add the functionality of zoom in/zoom out. I am using [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) to display PDF in my web app. A/C to the [documentation](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) there is a `scale prop` by using which I can `scale` the pdf page.

But using `scale prop` doesn't showing me any change in `zoom` factor. Here is the `code` which I am using to do so.

```
<Document
        loading=""
        file={file}
        className="document"
        onLoadSuccess={(transport) => onLoadSuccess(transport, sectionIndex)}>
        <Page width={900} scale={30} className="page" pageNumber={1} />
    </Document>
```

I have tried following values for `scale` `prop` but doesn't seem to get anything. 1.5, 0.5 , 10 , 30 ,40.
Is there any better way of doing the same or I am missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Change it to `scale={5.0}` (or whatever value you want to test), you'll get zoomed in.

The `scale` prop takes a decimal value separated by `.`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't have a hard coded width and change the scale, from just having this issue myself. My approach is going to be multiplying the page width by a tracked ratio in internal state.

Comment: I wonder how this is done considering the fixed width.

Comment: This is a comment in the property definition:
` If you define width and scale at the same time, the width will be multiplied by a given factor.`